# React, updating array to a new array doesn't re-render the dom with the new array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

so i'm looping over an array, and every element has a click event :

```
{optionsCategory.map((c,i) => (
     <div className="content" key={i} onClick={(e) => handleCategoryClick(e,c)}>
        {c.name}
     </div>
     ))}
```

upon clicking if the element has a subCategory i want to assing the subCategory array to the optionsCategory

```
const handleCategoryClick = async (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLHeadingElement>, c: Category) => {
if(c.subCategories.length > 0) {
  setOptionsService([...c.subCategories])
  console.log([optionsCategory])
}
else{
  setIsCategory(true);
  const data = await onActsByServiceIdAndCategoryId(serviceId,c.id);
  setActs([...data])
  console.log(acts);
}}
```

in the console the optionsCategory is updated but not in the Dom

Comment: In react, the component only rerenders when the component's props or it's state changes. Here, if you are not using the state for the options category, your component will not update. Can you please share your code as to what  `setOptionsService ` does? Try using `useState` hook

Comment: Is `optionsCategory` a value of `useState`? If so, what's the setter function? Can you share more details please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, after looking at it i used setOptionsService instead of setOptionCategory

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your optionsCategories inside a useState hook, then react will update the dom, for example: https://jsfiddle.net/7u9cqtxd/

In this case, every two seconds i'll push a new value to optionsCategory and react will update the dom.

```
const [optionsCategory, setCategory] = useState([30, 20, 10]);
      
setTimeout(() => setCategory([ ...optionsCategory, 50]), 2000);

return (
  <div>
    {optionsCategory.map((category) =>
    <li key={category}>
      {category}
    </li>
  )}
  </div>
);
```